# Example for function $f$ continuous at $(a,b,c)$ respect to each of the 3 variables, but fail to be continuous at $(a,b,c)$

Tags: calculus

Example for function $f$ defined on set $A⊂R^3$ and point $(a,b,c)∈A$, so that $f$ is continuous at $(a,b,c)$ respect to each of the 3 variables, but fail to be continuous at $(a,b,c)$

I'm working on finding the counter example, but haven't found any yet. I wonder if anyoen can give me a hint.

Comment: For $(a,b,c,)=(0,0,0)$ let $f$ be $0$ on the coordinate axes and $1$ elsewhere. (I may be misinterpreting your question.)

Comment: Can you explain it a little further please. You mean the piecewise function where $f(0,0,0)=0$ but $f(a,b,c)=1$ for non zero a,b,c ?

Comment: $f(x,0,0)=f(0,y,0)=f(0,0,z)=0$ for all $x$, $y$, $z$. $f$ has the value $1$ elsewhere. $f$ is not continuous at the origin, but each of $f(x,0,0)$, $f(0,y,0)$, $f(0,0,z)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{xyz}{x^3+y^3+z^3} & (x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0) \\
       0 & (x,y,z)=(0,0,0) 
   \end{cases}$$
suffices. Consider the sequences: $p_k=\left(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}\right)$ and $q_k=\left(\frac{1}{k},0,0\right)$. Then $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f\left(p_k\right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(1/k)^3}{3(1/k)^3}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$
but $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}f\left(q_k\right)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(1/k)\cdot0\cdot0}{(1/k)^3+0+0}=0$$ which shows that  the limit $$\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}f(x,y,z)$$ does not exist. On the other hand it is easy to check that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,y,z)=\lim_{y\rightarrow0}f(x,y,z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(x,y,z)=0$$ which shows that $f$ is continuous with respect to each variable but fail to be continuous at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: You should add why for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I think you want cubes downstairs, not squares. (So that $f((a,a,a))=1/3$.)

Comment: @David, Yes, I will edit and provide the proof.